# how to format a column with duplicate dates in r

Tags: r, datetime, xts

I have a fairly large dataset saved in a `.txt` file, that i read into my environment using `fread()` from `data.table`. I would like to organize the data so that it looks like this:

```
# Desired output: Column headers = [ Date, Company Names, RET, RETX,PRC, vwretd, ewrtd, sprtrn]
# rows contain stock return data... (I made up the values below to save time, but the format must remain).


   Date        AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO   ALASKA JUNEAU GOLD MNG C      RET       RETX   vwretd ...
1925-12-31          0.0432                    0.0231                 0.0032     0.053   ...
1926-01-02          0.0210                    0.0133                 0.0124     0.003   ...
1926-01-04          0.0324                    0.0131                 0.0134     0.023   ...
...                 ...                      ...                      ...        ...    ...
```

The only problem is that I am having trouble because my `crsp$date` column has duplicate Dates 
(SEE REPRODUCIBLE DATA), as the data seems to be `row binded`

Here is what I run when I import data using `fread()`

```
crsp <- fread("/Volumes/share/CRSP/CRSP_RETS/1925-1930.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
crsp <- as.data.frame(crsp)
```

After import I run the following to format `date` column

```
crsp$DATE <- as.Date(as.character(crsp$date),format="%Y%m%d")
```

I then try to convert to XTS

```
data <- xts(crsp[,3:11], crsp$DATE)
```

`data` returns the following: [ `dput(data)` ]

```
data <- structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", 
"AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", "AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", "ALASKA JUNEAU GOLD MNG CO", 
"AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", "ALASKA JUNEAU GOLD MNG CO", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "109.0000", "109.1250", "111.0000", "  1.8750", 
"110.5000", "  1.7500", "C", "0.001147", "0.017182", "C", "-0.004505", 
"-0.066667", "C", "0.001147", "0.017182", "C", "-0.004505", "-0.066667", 
NA, " 0.005893", " 0.001277", " 0.001277", "-0.003984", "-0.003984", 
NA, " 0.009516", " 0.005780", " 0.005780", "-0.001927", "-0.001927", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC",    
class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(-1388620800, -1388448000, -1388275200, 
-1388275200, -1388188800, -1388188800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(6L, 
9L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("TICKER", "COMNAM", "TRDSTAT", 
"PRC", "RET", "RETX", "vwretd", "ewretd", "sprtrn")))
```

## REPRODUCIBLE DATA

```
crsp <- structure(list(PERMNO = c(10006L, 10006L, 10006L, 10006L, 10006L, 
10006L, 10006L, 10006L, 10006L, 10014L, 10014L, 10014L, 10014L, 
10014L, 10014L, 10014L, 10014L), date = c(19251231L, 19260102L, 
19260104L, 19260105L, 19260106L, 19260107L, 19301229L, 19301230L, 
19301231L, 19260104L, 19260105L, 19260106L, 19260107L, 19260108L, 
19260109L, 19260111L, 19260112L), TICKER = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), COMNAM = c("AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", "AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", 
"AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", "AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", "AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", 
"AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", "AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", "AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", 
"AMERICAN CAR & FDRY CO", "ALASKA JUNEAU GOLD MNG CO", "ALASKA JUNEAU GOLD MNG CO", 
"ALASKA JUNEAU GOLD MNG CO", "ALASKA JUNEAU GOLD MNG CO", "ALASKA JUNEAU GOLD MNG CO", 
"ALASKA JUNEAU GOLD MNG CO", "ALASKA JUNEAU GOLD MNG CO", "ALASKA JUNEAU GOLD MNG CO"
), TRDSTAT = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), PRC = c(109, 109.125, 111, 
110.5, 110.5, 110.5, 24.25, 24.5, 27.5, 1.875, 1.75, 1.75, -1.8125, 
1.75, -1.6875, 1.625, NA), RET = c("C", "0.001147", "0.017182", 
"-0.004505", "0.000000", "0.000000", "-0.034826", "0.010309", 
"0.122449", "C", "-0.066667", "0.000000", "0.035714", "-0.034483", 
"-0.035714", "-0.037037", ""), RETX = c("C", "0.001147", "0.017182", 
"-0.004505", "0.000000", "0.000000", "-0.034826", "0.010309", 
"0.122449", "C", "-0.066667", "0.000000", "0.035714", "-0.034483", 
"-0.035714", "-0.037037", ""), vwretd = c(NA, 0.005893, 0.001277, 
-0.003984, -0.000172, 0.007211, -0.002367, 0.020064, 0.016505, 
0.001277, -0.003984, -0.000172, 0.007211, -0.000804, 0.003384, 
-0.00868, -0.001027), ewretd = c(NA, 0.009516, 0.00578, -0.001927, 
0.001182, 0.008453, -0.017949, 0.016016, 0.052093, 0.00578, -0.001927, 
0.001182, 0.008453, -0.001689, 0.003312, -0.009943, -0.003623
), sprtrn = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("PERMNO", 
"date", "TICKER", "COMNAM", "TRDSTAT", "PRC", "RET", "RETX", 
"vwretd", "ewretd", "sprtrn"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 1483L, 1484L, 1485L, 1486L, 1487L, 1488L, 1489L, 1490L, 
1491L, 1492L, 1493L), class = "data.frame")
```

Format `date` column ( same code as above)

```
crsp$DATE <- as.Date(as.character(crsp$date),format="%Y%m%d")
data <- xts(crsp[,3:11], crsp$DATE)
```

## UPDATE

Code produced by @akrun works efficiently with sample data but I am having trouble with actual dataset:

```
# this code works well on actual data
crsp1 <- crsp[,c(4, 6:12)];library(reshape2)

# this is the part where I am having difficulty with
crsp2 <- dcast(crsp1[,c(1:2, 8)], DATE~COMNAM, value.var="PRC")
```

It returns the following error: `Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length` 
This is a sample of what `crsp2` returns:

```
crsp2 <- structure(list(DATE = structure(c(-16072, -16070, -16068, -16067, 
-16066), class = "Date"), `A P W PAPER CO` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
`ABITIBI POWER & PAPER LTD` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `ABRAHAM & STRAUSS INC` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), `ADAMS EXPRESS CO` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("DATE", 
"A P W PAPER CO", "ABITIBI POWER & PAPER LTD", "ABRAHAM & STRAUSS INC", 
"ADAMS EXPRESS CO"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

As far as `format` , it returns the desired output, but the problem is that it returns 1's and 0's instead of actual values...
I believe it returns 1's where data is found/starts, and 0's where no data is found. I later tried specifying the `Aggregation function` :

```
# Specification of aggregation function plus "fill" to try to fix length errors & "drop" to
# avoid values being dropped
crsp2 <- dcast(crsp1[,c(1:2, 8)], DATE ~ COMNAM, value.var="RET", fun.aggregate= length, fill=  
0);library(plyr);
```

This time, I do not get any errors but still get the 1's and 0's. Perhaps it might be better to seperate the data by `COMNAM` and then index by `DATE` column, so that I can just `merge()` or `cbind()` to get the desired output. But i do not know if there is a better way? I have also tried the following functions but left them running for more than 6 hours and came back and where still running... cannot seem to make them work...

```
# daply() from library(plyr)
crsp2 <- daply(crsp1[,c(1:2, 8)], .(DATE,COMNAM), function(x) x$PRC, .parallel=TRUE)


# reshape()
crsp2 <- reshape(crsp1[,c(1:2, 8)], idvar="COMNAM", timevar="DATE", direction="wide")
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a reproducible example.  I have a doubt regarding the values that fill up the company name columns in the desired output.  Is it the `PRC` column?

Comment: @akrun thanks for responding... Yeah looks like I left out the PRC out by accident. And some values are negative, but i have to format them later...The desired output is how I want to format it, and I made up the values to save time, the actual values will differ

Comment: So, does it belong to PRC column or something else?  I got confused by your reply.  Also, why you are using `xts` if your expected output shows `DATE` as a column?

Comment: @akrun yes Those values belong to PRC. I basically wish to keep all the numeric columns/values. I would prefer xts as I can later facilitate and run the data with packages such as quantmod, PerformanceAnalytics etc.

Comment: You could get the expected output format by `crsp1 <- crsp[,c(4, 6:12)];library(reshape2);crsp2 <- dcast(crsp1[,c(1:2, 8)], DATE~COMNAM, value.var="PRC");library(plyr);join(crsp1[,-(1:2)], crsp2)`

Comment: @akrun Thanks, this seems to get the desired output on the sample data I provided, however I get different results on the actual data... I only get "1" or "0" where the values should be. I believe this is because the start dates for each stock differ but I do not know how to overcome this? I have tried `drop=FALSE`

Comment: @akrun sample of what it `crsp2` looks like: crsp2 <-structure(list(DATE = structure(c(-16072, -16070, -16068, -16067, 
-16066), class = "Date"), `A P W PAPER CO` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), `ABITIBI POWER & PAPER LTD` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), `ABRAHAM & STRAUSS INC` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `ADAMS EXPRESS CO` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("DATE", 
"A P W PAPER CO", "ABITIBI POWER & PAPER LTD", "ABRAHAM & STRAUSS INC", 
"ADAMS EXPRESS CO"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: When I copied and pasted your `crsp2`, it gave errors.  Could you update it in your post rather than in the comment.  Also, it would be better to provide the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues related to `xts` here:

1. `xts` assumes weakly monotonic ordering of the index. Duplicate index values are allowed, but you should not rely on the ordering of the duplicate values (and lots of warnings may be thrown if you have repeated index entries).  So for timestamp data we use helpers like `make.time.unique()` which add  the smallest possible epsilon to separate them.
2. `xts` uses a matrix as the data container, which means you cannot mix types (e.g. you can only have numeric data, or only character data, etc).

So here, a `data.frame` with an added `Date` column, or a `data.table`, may be better.