# Missing values using reshape2

Tags: r, reshape2

My question is very similar to the one posted here. I am trying to use reshape data to turn CRSP data from long format to wide. I have the tickers of S&P companies stacked in one column and I want to make them the columns instead. In my dataframe I have three columns: "DATE", "TICKER", and "PRC". (PRC is price).
I would like instead to have the number of columns equal my unique tickers. I use:

```
dcast(df, DATE~TICKER, value.var="PRC"), fun.aggregate=length, fill=NaN, drop=FALSE)
```

This returns the perfect dataframe sorting the time series date on the left and tickers on the right, but just like the question I linked to, I get 1's and NaN's as my values. I like the NaN's, but I would want the 1's to be replaced with the prices of my securities aka the PRC.

I get 1's and 0's because some tickers are missing data, which makes sense as some stocks get into and out of the S&P 500. I just have no idea why the `value.var` command is being blatantly ignored.

[how to format a column with duplicate dates in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699596/how-to-format-a-column-with-duplicate-dates-in-r#new-answer?newreg=4e25e5a3749445d29ece6e393760567f)

Comment: Can you post a sample dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Without a working dataset, here is all I can really provide.

```
data.melt <- melt(df, id.vars=c('TICKER','DATE'), measure.vars='PRC')
data.cast <- dcast(data.melt, TICKER~DATE, sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

The value.var isn't being ignored.  The problem is that you're specifying `fun.aggregate=length`.  That means that it isn't going to give you the actual values but the result of an aggregate function, in this case `length` so you're getting 1s and 0s because you either have missing data (a 0) or 1 data point.

Try taking out fun.aggregate.  Sometimes it's fussy when there's missing data so you might get an error so then bring back fun.aggregate but replace `length` with `sum` or `mean`